# Calculate MySQL coordinate and update rows

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, coordinates, distance

I need to loop through a table with coordinates (lat,long in the same column) and compare them with a given value. If the distance is lower than 1 km, another column of the row that respect the condition is updated.

Something like this:

```
Foreach row in Table
if CalculateDistance(lat1,long1,lat2,long2) < 1
Update row.Column2
```

I found a formula to calculate, here: https://gist.github.com/Usse/4086343

At this moment I am trying to test the formula.

Thank you

**EDIT 1:**

So I created the procedure but I am stuck.

I created a split string function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `strSplit`(x varchar(255), delim varchar(12), pos int) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
return replace(substring(substring_index(x, delim, pos), length(substring_index(x, delim, pos - 1)) + 1), delim, '')
```

And my stored procedure of update the table is this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `turn_camera_on`(coordonates varchar(50))
BEGIN

DECLARE lat1 varchar(50);
DECLARE long1 varchar(50);

SET lat1 = strSplit(coordonates, ',', 1);
SET long1 = strSplit(coordonates, ',', 2);

UPDATE deviceinfo
SET CameraOn = 1
where CalculateDistance(lat1,long1,**lat2,long2**) < 1;

END
```

The issue is that lat2 and long2 are a string in a row, in the table...

Comment: UPDATE my_table SET column2 = x WHERE Calcu.... < 1

Comment: Or is your question about how to break out the lat. and long. from their common column?

Comment: I think Straberry game me the answer. I'll come back with updates asap

Comment: Just use your `strSplit` function on whatever column in the table contains  lat2,long2; like you did with `coordonates` to get lat1 and long1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, this does what you want:

```
DECLARE v_lat1 varchar(50);
DECLARE v_long1 varchar(50);

SET lat1 = strSplit(v_coordinates, ',', 1);
SET long1 = strSplit(v_coordinates, ',', 2);
UPDATE deviceinfo di
    SET CameraOn = 1
WHERE CalculateDistance(v_lat1, v_long1, strSplit(di.coordinates, ',', 1), strSplit(di.coordinates, ',', 2)) < 1;
```

However, defining your own split functions seems quite superfluous in MySQL.  You can just write:

```
UPDATE deviceinfo di
    SET CameraOn = 1
WHERE CalculateDistance(substring_index(v_coordinates, ',', 1),
                        substring_index(v_coordinates, ',', -1),
                        substring_index(di.coordinates, ',', 1),
                        substring_index(di.coordinates, ',', -1);
```

Also, some notes:

- Always define table aliases (the `di` in the above queries).
- Always qualify column names (the `di.` in the above queries).
- Prefix variable and parameter names so they are not confused with columns (the `v_`) in the above queries.